# flutterfire configure returns error when trying to set up project with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, backend

I'm new to flutter and also have no experience in back-end coding. I am following a freeCodeCamp tutorial on flutter and when trying to set up firebase, I keep getting an error when running **flutterfire** configure. If you need any more info, let me know thank you.

```
⠼ Fetching available Firebase projects...
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:278:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:368:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     main (file:///C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutterfire_cli-0.2.6+1/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: try running the command on windows cmd.if it didn't work check this: [link](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/issues/55)

Comment: the best tutorial to follow is the official documentation. Unofficial tutorials are most of the time outdated.